# General Chrome Extension DevOps Flow

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have been developing a Chrome Extention and curious a couple of things.

**1. How do you track users' behavior in a content script using tools like LogRocket?**

Remoted hosted code is not allowed so try to thing of the way to implement it.

**2. How can I ship hot fixes ASAP?**

Shipping a extension takes time and curious how other people handle to fix the bug and ship it sooner. I have used react native and `eas update` which only deploys JS code but not entire build. Would it be possible to do the similar stuff?

https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/introduction/

Thanks!

Comment: You're asking two questions here, both of which are broad. Please see [ask] and take the [tour] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate. Ask just one _specific_ question per post.